# Excel - Lookup to return multiple values in between date range

Tags: excel

I want to return multiple values, in this case the "Total Adjustment" that are associated with each effective date that falls (strictly) in between a given Start Date and an End Date.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZTd8.png

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [AVERAGEIFS()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIFS-function-48910c45-1fc0-4389-a028-f7c5c3001690?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1):

```
=AVERAGEIFS(B2:B48,A2:A48,">=" & D5,A2:A48,"<=" & E5)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, Thanks!

Comment: @adam I am glad it worked for you.  please mark as correct.  It is something only you can do.  Click on the green check mark by the answer