# Excel returning multiple values for a date range, with a single date items summed

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, calendar

I have the opposite query for this question:

[Excel - Lookup to return multiple values in between date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35044030/excel-lookup-to-return-multiple-values-in-between-date-range)

The solution is given for the above query in the following link also:

https://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/12/13/formula-for-matching-a-date-within-a-date-range-in-excel/

But my query is that for multiple date ranges, how do I find the total bookings of a single date.

I wish to build a calendar which will allow me to work out how many booking I have for a certain day. All the bookings are for 1 or more items and I want the total items which will be there on a single day, across a date calendar range.

[image: Date range and total items staying for that date range, with calendar]

On the calendar on the right side, I wish to add the total items which will be staying over during that specified date.

So, in the example, on the 26th December, a total of 6 items will be there. And for 5th December there is only 1, while for 1st December there are no items.

Would like to have these numbers in the calendar on the right.

I have tried using VLOOKUP, LOOKUP, INDEX and MATCH.
Also, tried the SUMPRODUCT mentioned, but those seem to give a single range and number for that range, but not the multiple values across a date range.

https://chandoo.org/wp/range-lookup-excel/

Formulae I tried are, for the 26th December date are:

```
=(LOOKUP(H10,((Table1[Date From]):(Table1[Date To])),Table1[Items from]))

=SUMIF(Table1[Item],(LOOKUP(2,1/(Table1[Date From]<=H10)/(Table1[Date To]>=H10))))

=INDEX(Table1[Item from],MATCH(H10,LOOKUP(H10,Table1[[Date From]:[Date To]])))
```

Comment: Another solution which is close is:

https://contexturesblog.com/archives/2013/02/26/sum-for-a-date-range-in-excel/

Comment: Your screenshot of data is virtually useless for doing proper troubleshooting. It cannot be copy/pasted into a worksheet. One can try an OCR program, or manually enter it. Having to do either of these is discouraging to those who might assist you. To make the data useful edit your question to post it as text, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables), or possibly upload a workbook (with sensitive information removed) to some public website and post a link in your original question

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, thank you for the answer and it works perfectly! :-)     I have tried to copy the exact content, but seems the image action is the default one. Will upload the excel to a public site next time and use that for the example reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Dec 26th (*and keeping your original structure*)

```
=SUMIFS(Bookings[[Items]:[Items]],Bookings[[Date From]:[Date From]],"<=" &H10,Bookings[[Date To]:[Date To]],">="&H10)
```

Note that I used the absolute address structured reference form so you can at least fill/drag across a row, without changing the columns from the table.

If you want to make things even easier, you can replace the `H10` reference with a computed reference, but at the cost of using `OFFSET` which is a volatile function.

```
=SUMIFS(Bookings[[Items]:[Items]],Bookings[[Date From]:[Date From]],"<=" &OFFSET(H$1,ROW()-2,0),Bookings[[Date To]:[Date To]],">="&OFFSET(H$1,ROW()-2,0))
```

You might also be able to construct a computed cell reference using the `INDEX` function, which would be non-volatile.

Answer (score 1):

### Updated answer with array formulas

Sorry for not understanding your first request.

You can use the following array formula in a "single cell"

```
{= SUM( IF( (E2 >=$B$2:$B$8 ) * (E2<=$C$2:$C$8) ; $A$2:$A$8 ; 0 ))}
```

Where column `e` contains the target dates, columns `a`, `b` and `c` contain `items`, `from` and `to`.

This formula is expansible and copiable to other cells where `e2` will be relatively changed for each target date. This is easily adaptable to your month table. Put the formula below the first date, then expand horizontally and copy/paste to the other rows.

See picture:

[image: new picture with column dates]

### Old answer

- Create a separate cell with your target date. Suppose `$e$1`.
- Create on `e2` this formula: `=if( and( $e$1 >= c2 ; $e$1 <= d2 ); a2; 0)`
- Expand it and sum at the bottom.

Sorry for my formulas in Portuguese in the image (se = if ; e = and):

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this, I have tried this, but it makes the solution too complex and long. I will have to create a column for each date in this solution and then sum it up. Anytime a new time comes, the rows (and columns) will just keep adding. I was wanting to avoid that and get a single number for each date in the format I have given above.  If I given this formula, it returns 0, for the above: =IF(AND(($H$10>=C2),($H$10 <= D2)),A2,0)  ... which is correct, but can I do something like:      =IF(AND(($H$10>=C2:C14),($H$10 <= D2:D14)),(SUMIF(A2:A14),0)??

Comment: The formula I have given {IF(AND(($H$10>=C2:C14),($H$10 <= D2:D14)),(SUMIF(A2:A14),0)} will not work obviously, but want something which can give a single cell answer to the problem, not having to create multiple columns and then get an answer.

Comment: Ok, @gagneet, now I understand what you wanted. See updated answer.